# How can i install Laravel on my shared hosting without using composer.phar

Tags: laravel-4, composer-php

Hi what i have tried till now.

I have installed composer on my mac
I have installed MAMP

I have installed Laravel on my mac at: /laravel

using this guide: http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/quick#installation

Now when i go to my localhost/laravel

I see a welcome message

but when i uploaded the same on my shared hosting server. I see a blank page :(

Anything i should do to get it working ?

Answer (score 1):

On your remote server you'd normally need to configure the document root to point to the `public` directory from your Laravel installation. Unfortunately that's generally not possible on shared servers, so you'll need to work around that. Here's a comprehensive article explaining 3 different methods of deploying Laravel on shared servers:

> **http://driesvints.com/blog/laravel-4-on-a-shared-host**